# My open-cart store and admin panel is not opening

Tags: php, opencart

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, I have searched lot in web can't able to get the solutions for my error

**Error Getting**

> Warning: require_once(D:/WWWRoot/root/AAAFashions/system/framework.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\WWWRoot\root\AAAFashions\system\startup.php on line 124
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'D:/WWWRoot/root/AAAFashions/system/framework.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   D:\WWWRoot\root\AAAFashions\system\startup.php on line 124

I don't know how to resolve this, am new to open cart, please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you check on your hard drive if this file exists? `D:/WWWRoot/root/AAAFashions/system/framework.php`

Comment: no file is not there

Comment: now I have newly installed the opencart and copied framework.php to D:/WWWRoot/root/AAAFashions/system/

Comment: Is it working now?